# In a 2 D array with 2 columns a & b. For all the same values in column a, pick corresponding value from column b in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a two dimensional array with two columns namely a and b. Now for all the same values in column a, I want to pick corresponding value from column b in the same row and create an output array with it. 
For example -
array

```
row | column a | column b
0   | 10       |12
1   | 11       |15
2   | 10       |14
```

Output array should be:-
Array(12,14)

How do I go about it in Php?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this should work:

```
// Lets presume that original array looks like this:
$array = [[10, 12], [11, 15], [10, 14]];

$newArray = [];

// Lets traverse the array and "key" it by first value from each row:
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $newArray[$row[0]][] = $row[1];
}

// New array should look like this:
$newArray = [10 => [12, 14], 11 => [15]];

// So you just need to access the key:
$newArray[10] = [12, 14];
```

Let me know if it worked. Mind you that I'm using short array syntax here which is available from PHP5.4. Let me know if you are using older PHP version.